# How many rational numbers $m/n$ are possible under given conditions?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, solution-verification

Find the number of rational numbers $m/n$, where $m,n$ are relatively prime positive integers satisfying $m<n$ and $mn=25!$.

***My Approach:***

Let $25!=2^{a_1}3^{a_2}5^{a_3}\ldots19^{a_8}23^{a_9}$

Now $\gcd(m,n)\Rightarrow\ $ If $p|m$ then $p\not|n$

**Case I**:

> There is $1$ prime factor of $m$
> Thus, the number of rational number $m/n=\binom{9}{1}$

**Case II:**

> There are $2$ prime factor of $m$
> Thus, the number of rational number $m/n=\binom{9}{2}$

**Case III:**

> There are $3$ prime factor of $m$
> Thus, the number of rational number $m/n=\binom{9}{3}$

**Case IV:**

> There are $4$ prime factor of $m$
> Thus, the number of rational number $m/n=\binom{9}{4}$

If in any of these rational numbers, if $m>n$, then interchanging $m$ and $n$ would result in a valid rational number.

For example: Suppose for some $m=p_1^{a_1}p_2^{a_2}p_3^{a_3}$, $m>n$, then interchanging $m$ and $n$ would give $n=p_1^{a_1}p_2^{a_2}p_3^{a_3}$, which means that now $m<n$ thus giving a valid rational number.

Thus the number of possible rational numbers is $\binom{9}{1}+\binom{9}{2}+\binom{9}{3}+\binom{9}{4}+1=2^8$

Now I'm not sure whteher this is correct and the book I am refering to hasn't provided a solution. Therefore please check this solution and provide any suggestions.

***THANKS***

Comment: More simply:  there are exactly $9$ primes $≤25$. Specifying $m$ is the same as specifying any subset of those primes, and then of course $n$ is the complimentary subset.  Thus the answer should be $2^9$.  Not sure why you ended up losing a factor of $2$, or how I gained one...

Comment: Correction:  You were correct to divide by $2$, I ignored the condition $m<n$.   I agree that the answer should be $2^8$.

Comment: Losing that factor of 2 was because of the condition $m<n$, which would reduce the number of possible subsets to half the previous value. That approach is a lot simpler hence beautiful. Is this approach also correct?

Comment: Agreed.  So, yes, your methodology and computation are correct.  Might be worth one line to remark that $m=n$ is impossible under the construction we have given (since $\gcd(m,n)=1$).

Comment: @lulu Thanks for the help.

Comment: @lulu Would you please write the simpler version as answer so that I may accept?

Comment: If you post your solution below, I'll review it and upvote it (and I believe you can accept your own post).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the help provided by lulu in the comments above, I think this solution provided by lulu might be simpler and better:

Let $S$ be the set of primes $<25$.
$$S=\{2,3,\ldots19,23\}$$

Choosing the factor $m$ here is the same as choosing a subset $M\subseteq S$ with $N\subseteq S$ as the complementary set. $(M\cap N=\phi)$

Since $S$ has $9$ elements, the number of such subsets $M=2^9$.

Also $M\neq N$ or $m\neq n$ since $\gcd(m,n)=1$.

After taking into account the condition $m<n$, the number of such subsets $M$ and hence the rational numbers $=2^9/2=2^8$

Comment: Looks good (+1).  As I mentioned in an earlier comment, it might be worth mentioning that this construction can't produce a pair with $m=n$ since we are guaranteed $\gcd(m,n)=1$.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add this line.